# Getting error DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. when setting user data in Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to save user data from firebase into firestore and I keep getting this error

```
DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field 
value: undefined (found in field uid)
```

Here are the 2 methods involved:

```
  register(credentials) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password).then(user => {
      return this.setUserDoc(user);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error.message));
  }

  private setUserDoc(user) {
    console.log(user);
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const data: User = {
      uid: user.uid, <-- says this is undefined
      email: user.email
    }

    return userRef.set(data);
  }
```

If I `console.log(user)` that is passed into the `setUserDoc` method I can open it and it has a `uid` but if I `console.log(user.uid)` it says undefined. Can someone help me figure out why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out. I was just one level too high. if I changed the call to pass `credential.user` it worked. So now the code is:

```
register(credentials) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password).then(credential => {
      return this.setUserDoc(credential.user); <-- changed what was passed
    }).catch(error => alert(error.message));
  }
```